# Improving an if count == x case

Tags: php, if-statement, count

I was just wondering, how can I improve this code?

```
  $count = count($data['tags']);
  if($count > 3)
  {
    $hashtags = implode(',', array_slice($data['tags'], 0,3));
  }
  elseif($count !== 0)
  {
    $hashtags = implode(',', array_slice($data['tags'], 0,$count));
  }
  else
  {
    $hashtags = 'data';
  }
```

Btw, wasn't there a section on stackoverflow to ask for possibles code improvements? Can't find it in the footer links

**EDIT:**

By improvement I was mainly thinking about shorthand and than I was looking for a different approach for the same thing (just to learn something new) Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: There is [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), it's not in the footer because it's still in beta.

Comment: What exactly do you want to improve?  Speed, readability, result or something else?

Comment: What's wrong with it? Improve it how?

Comment: Yea the code works fine, but I was looking for a different approach for the same thing (just to learn something new) and by improvement I was thinking about shorthand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested since I don't code in PHP, but how about this?

```
$count = count($data['tags']);
$hashtags = $count == 0 ? 'data' :
   implode(',', array_slice($data['tags'], 0,min(3,$count)));
```

Comment: @ComFreek - Agreed, but "improve" wasn't really defined by the OP. I assumed maybe they wanted to simplify the code a bit. But I agree it's not necessarily more readable, just fewer lines of code, which isn't always "better".

Answer (score 4):

A difficult question to answer.

What do you mean by "improve"?

Provided the code does what you need it to do(and I assume that it does), and is relatively easy to read and maintain(I was unfamiliar with a couple of the php functions, but after looking them up, your code reads just fine for me), then your code doesn't need "improvement".

Answer (score 2):

You could write the same this like this:

```
$count = count($data['tags']);
$hashtags = $count !== 0 ? implode(',', array_slice($data['tags'], 0, min($count, 3))) : 'data';
```

It's fewer lines of code, but not really more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to make it all one line, but it may not be an improvement.  Your code looks fine to me.

```
$hashtags = $count === 0 ? 'data' : implode(',', array_slice($data['tags'], 0, ($count > 3) ? 3 : $count));
```

Comment: @AleksG: Thanks for editing, guess I still need more Mt. Dew.

Comment: No problem :) I figured with 20K reputation it was a typo.

Comment: @AleksG: I was trying to make sure I had enough `)` at the end, guess I missed the `$count` :-P

Comment: Yep, that was it, missing `$count` after the `:`